# TypeError: execute_script() missing 1 required positional argument: 'script'

Tags: python, selenium, arguments, typeerror, captcha

this worked earlier and now it does not anymore, i know its something to do with these three lines. i am just not sure what though?

```
driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";') # Making Token Input Visible

driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]""", g_response) # Pasting New Token

driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="none";') # Hiding Token Input Again
```

this is the error message i get:

```
 File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Bots Coded By Me\Bot\solverr.py", line 34, in solvecaptcha
    driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";') # Making Token Input Visible
TypeError: execute_script() missing 1 required positional argument: 'script'
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the set the value of *style* property to ***`none`*** you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display = "none";')
```

Comment: didnt do anything,

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.